# Reading status and XY-coordinates from GPS-widget with PyQGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, gps, xy, widget

Is there a way to access the status and the XY-coordinates from a GPS-connection established by the GPS-widget in QGIS 3 via Python?

I want to establish the connection with the widget to have better control of the connection (like changing ports) and status checks, but need the coordinates inside a Python plugin.

Comment: This is a good one!  There is a panel to view GPS in the menu  View-  Panels-  GPS information.   There must be a way to get that info.

Comment: Seems to be a bigger issue.. even in the QGIS mailinglist I got no reaction to this question.

Comment: When keeping the map always centered over the current position, it is possible to get the coordinates with canvas = iface.mapCanvas() canvas.center() .

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187985/accessing-gps-from-qgis-2-14-1-python-2-7-windows10   This is a QGIS 2 response but we can look for the same function in QGIS 3.4 docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @CaryH I found a solution.

For QGIS 2:

```
QgsGpsConnectionRegistry().instance()
```

For QGIS 3:

```
QgsApplication.gpsConnectionRegistry()
```

So using the following code

```
connectionRegistry = QgsApplication.gpsConnectionRegistry()
connectionList = connectionRegistry.connectionList()
GPSInfo = connectionList[0].currentGPSInformation()
```

After that it is possible to access all information of the widget-gps-connection using for example

```
GPSInfo.elevation
GPSInfo.latitude
```

All available commands are listed at https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.2/core/Gps/QgsGpsInformation.html