# QGIS 3.14.15: is there a build in option for storing additonal quality data from trackpoints captured with DGPS antenna

Tags: qgis-3, gps, accuracy, nmea

I'd like to use QGIS for collecting datapoints in field. Due to the 'GPS information module' it is no big deal to connect the R2-Antenna via Blutooth-link and read the NMEA stream.

As far as I figured out till now, QGIS- stores the XY(Z) data according to layer properties where I store my points.

I'd like to store information about acquisition quality e.g. fix-time, accuracy, satelites, etc. as attributes.
I could find some stuff in qgis.core.QgsGps...but obviously need to be pushed in the right direction.
Even the storing of the entire $G[PNA]GGA sentence would be a solution.

Can someone give me some hints or point to the right plugin to look for or to use the QGIS-internal Python classes?

Using Python with pymmea2 allows reading all that data on plain Python level but it's not my aim writing my own GUI for that purpose.

Comment: Just being pedantic here, please change "R2-Antenna" to "R2 receiver".  Reason: R2 is a complete GNSS receiver not just a GNSS antenna.

Answer (score 0):

I meanwhile found a solution for my problem, terribly  I have trouble getting access to my initial post and ended up having another account. Therefore no editing possible to make Trams happy.

[Read status and XY-coordinates from GPS-widget with Python (QGIS 3)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306653/read-status-and-xy-coordinates-from-gps-widget-with-python-qgis-3)

expalains how to get access to the data provided by a GNSS device.

To get them automaticaly written as an attribute there is the chance setting a default entry via layer's proerties/attribute form/your_field.
I wrote a tiny function within the function editor using the below to get the desired values and returned them in a string.

connectionRegistry = QgsApplication.gpsConnectionRegistry()
connectionList = connectionRegistry.connectionList()
GPSInfo = connectionList[0].currentGPSInformation()

This workaround works with  3.14.15 on windows.