# QGIS GPS Connection with PyQgis causes minidump

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gps, minidump

After some experimenting and reading source codes I tried to connect to my GPS device as follows (from a QGIS plugin):

```
self.pushButton_conGPS.clicked.connect(self.connectGPS)

[...]
def connectGPS(self):
    port = u'\\\\.\\COM4'
    #port = u'localhost:2947:'
    self.detector = QgsGPSDetector(port)
    print 'detected, connection functions'
    self.detector.detected[QgsGPSConnection].connect(self.connectionSucceed)
    print '---'
    self.detector.detectionFailed.connect(self.connectionFailed)
    print 'advance'
    self.detector.advance()

def connectionSucceed(self, connection):
    print 'connection Succeed'
    QgsGPSConnectionRegistry.instance().registerConnection(connection)
    print QgsGPSConnectionRegistry.instance().connectionList()[0].currentGPSInformation().utcDateTime.toString()

def connectionFailed(self):
    print 'connection failed.'
```

Pressing my above referred button results in

[image]

Note the output on the python console, minidump occurs at `QgsGPSConnectionRegistry.instance().registerConnection(connection)`

Related post: [Connect / Disconnect GPS device via PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188002/connect-disconnect-gps-device-via-pyqgis)

What is it that causes the minidump? I think similiar c++ code of the GPS Information panel works pretty well...