# Seeking GPS Hardware for QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, windows-10, hardware-recommendations

I have the same question as [QGIS live GPS tracking /recommended hardware (GPS USB stick)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/187050) which was posted 3 years ago. I use windows 10 and  USB 3.0. I have seen a lot of angry reviews about well known GPS device brands so I was wondering if anyone has been using GPS tool in QGIS and is willing to share info about type of device being used.

Answer (score 0):

QGIS supports both NMEA and Windows Location Service connected GPS hardware under Windows 10 as of some version of QGIS 3.0.x.

I deployed a number of BAK Seal Windows 10 tablets with QGIS3 using the in-built GPS hardware, as well as external/USB connected Ublox hardware using both the serial/NMEA drivers as well as Windows Location Service.

Attached a screenshot of WLS giving location via ISP/WiFi, as an example.

[image]